# using awk, how can I find the max value in a column, then print a different field of the row that data was found in?

Tags: text-processing, awk

The specific example I have is finding the max value in column 5, then the associated 2nd field with that value. For example:

```
1  text1  1   1   5
2  text2  2   2   10 
3  text3  3   3   15
4  text4  4   4   50
5  text5  5   5   25
```

here is my script.  it begins with a function for finding max, then attempts to print the 2nd field's data of the same row the max was found in.

```
function max(val1,val2){
        if (val1 > val2)
                return val1
        else
                return val2
}

BEGIN {largest = 0}

{largest = max(largest,$5 + 0)}
$5 ~ largest {print $2}

END {}
```

this ends up printing out

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
```

because it prints out the 2nd field every time it finds a new max.  I am trying to find a way for it to only print out only the last max found so it prints "text4" only.  I tried putting `"$5 ~ largest {print $2}"` in the end block but it gives a syntax error.

Comment: Can multiple rows have the same value in column 5 and, if so, do you want the value of the 1st associated 2nd field printed or the last or all of them or something else? Can the values in column 5 ever be negative?

Answer (score 8):

All your awk script can be simplified to this:

```
awk 'max<$5 || NR==1{ max=$5; data=$2 } END{ print data }' infile
```

or to "keep all lines' of second column with equal maximum values" in 5<sup>th</sup> column:

```
awk 'max<$5 || NR==1 { max=$5; data=$2; next }
     max==$5{ data= data ORS $2 }
END{ print data }' infile
```

---

About your own script you wrote like that, you needed to process the input file twice, first process find the max value, second process print the second column of the lines having that max value, something like this:

```
awk 'function max(val1, val2){
        if (val1 > val2)
                return val1
        else
                return val2
}

BEGIN { largest = 0 }

NR==FNR{ largest = max(largest,$5 + 0); next }
$5==largest { print $2 }' infile infile
```

Comment: could you explain this line a little bit? 
```
 max==$5{ data= (data==""? "": data ORS) $2 }
```
this did exactly what i needed it to but i do not quite understand what is going on.

Comment: @Ryan that part actually hold the column#2 of those line (one or more) having same maximum column#5 in appending mode.

Comment: @Ryan ?: is a ternary operator, basically shorthand for if/then/else. It says if data is blank then use that, otherwise add a record separator between the data values, then it adds $2 to the result.

Comment: @Ryan Only execute the following commands if $5 is equal to max for this row `{` set data equal to the following statement with the value of $2 tacked on to the end : `(` Is data equal to an empty string?  If it is, return an empty string, else (if it is not) return `data` followed by the Output Record Seperator (a newline `\n` by default) `)}`

Comment: @Ryan In more plain english, we are building up a single string `data` that we are going to print at the end. If we get a hit for the max number, we first check if `data` is an empty string, if it is we just set `data` to $2 for the current row.  If data already has some content in it, then we append a '\n' to the end followed by $2 for the current row.  This is a little confusing because it uses the ternary operator ` cond ? return if T : return if F` and it .....

Comment: ...uses awk's implicit string concatenation.  If variables are listed together with a space in-between, awk concatenates them together implicitly.  So `bob = data ORS $2` would get you `bob=1,000\n20` if data = 1,000 and $2=20 and we assume the default Output Record (ie line) Seperator of `\n`.   The only thing I am not sure of is if the ternary operator is needed. `data` is initialized to $2 of the first line, so I think it is guaranteed to be non-null unless you potentially have missing entries in $2, if so then this code just throws out those empty values.

Comment: @Cole thanks for pointing that, yes, not required to check `data` as it's initialized, that was needed only before I add `NR==1`. and yes required if first line for example was empty or there was no column#5, but for OP input it's there and preferred to remove ternary here. thanks again and your explanation for ternary

Answer (score 4):

I interpret your question as

> Find the max value in column 5, then print all values in column 2 that have that max value.

```bsh
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        if (FNR == 1 || $5 > max) max = $5
        next
    }
    $5 == max {print $2}
' file file
```

That processes the file twice: once to find the max, then again to print the matching values. I'm trading off reduced memory usage for increased run time.